# Full calendar in react add click event on header elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using [full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in my project. My requirement is to use click event on the header buttons like  prev, next and today buttons and so on.

Below is how I have used full calendar and the headers contains these given buttons.

```js
<FullCalendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  header={{
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
  }}
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
  ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
  weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
  events={this.state.calendarEvents}
  eventBorderColor={""}
  eventLimit={true}
  views={{
    timeGrid: {
      eventLimit: 3 // adjust to 3 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
    },
    dayGrid: {
      eventLimit: 4
    }
  }}
  viewRender={function(view, elm) {
    console.log(view, elm);
  }}
  // eventRender = {function(eventObj, elm) {
  //   console.log(eventObj , elm);

  // }}
  select={function(start, end) {
    console.log(start, end);
  }}
  slotDuration={"00:15:00"}
  slotLabelInterval={"00:05:00"}
  dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
/>;
```

I want to trigger a function while changing views from header. For example - While changing view  from dayGridMonth to timeGridWeek I want to reload the data. So I need to call a function. Same with the prev, next and today button.
Please help me out. If my given information is not clear I can provide more detailed explanation.

Comment: Try `https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons`

Comment: @DoubleH I went through this link and there is no hint of click event of the header buttons. It has shown how to add new buttons and their click events.

Comment: You can overwrite those buttons with your custom buttons and load new data by clicking button

Comment: "While changing view from dayGridMonth to timeGridWeek I want to reload the data"...this is why you set up event feeds (rather than passing a simple array of data to fullCalendar) - then fullCalendar will handle it automatically for you, without you needing to worry about the buttons (because apart from anything else they are not actually the only ways the view or date range can be changed). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for the two ways of supplying an event feed to fullCalendar dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the beta-v5 and the callback you need is datesDidUpdate.

In the version 4.4.2 they had the datesRender but it was causing issues in the UI.

Answer (score -1):

```
customButtons: {
                myCustomButton: {
                    text: 'reset',
                    click: function() {
                        var confirm_me = confirm('reset the event');
                        if(confirm_me){
                            this.resetEvent();
                        }
                    }
                },
                nextYear:{
                    click:function(){
                        calendar.nextYear();
                        this.current_active_date = calendar.getDate();
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Some intro words would be nice to summarize your code. Would make it an better answer overall.